# Deploy TestAgent fails with unhandled exception

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

The Deploy test agent task in TFS release definition fails with the below exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: The
>   WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the
>   overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing
>   methods, and they can only be called from within the same thread.
>   Validate that the cmdlet makes these calls correctly, or contact
>   Microsoft Customer Support Services. 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowIfWriteNotPermitted(Boolean
>   needsToWriteToPipeline) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteHelper_ShouldWrite(ActionPreference
>   preference, ContinueStatus lastContinueStatus)
>   2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteWarning(WarningRecord
>   record, Boolean overrideInquire) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteWarning(String text)
>   2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.Logger.WriteWarning(String
>   message) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.TestAgentDownloader.wc_DownloadFileCompleted(Object
>   sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadFileCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs
>   e) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) 2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   2017-06-16T08:49:49.9634068Z    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>   2017-06-16T08:49:55.4477257Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with
>   255 errors.

The task executes successfully if the Update test agent check box is not checked. 
 Solution mentioned here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2964 and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dae4c62d-cd23-40ad-83cf-2555d37c0bb9/test-agent-deployment-failing?forum=tfsbuild does not seems to work either

Comment: Hi Santhosh, any update info on this issue?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Thank you, will get back with the update asap.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Could you please let me know if there is any other way to overcome this error, we are stuck with this issue and seems to be a dead end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by downloading the testagent exe and copying the same to a share folder that has access to the build agents. This is configured under the advanced section and provide the share path under Test Agent Location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Advanced - Update test agent**
>
> If set, and **the test agent is already installed on the test
>   machines**, the task will check if a new version of the test agent is
>   available.

- First, check if the test agent is already intalled on the machines,
  if not this maybe the root cause.
- Try to do the deploy test agent with same settings in the build
  definition instead of release. This will narrow down if the issue is
  only related to release or not.
- Check the Even Log in the test agent machine if there are some useful
  info.
- Try to deploy the test agent to another machine with old test agent
  installed and "update test agent" checked.

Besides, if you are using TFS2017 update2Rc and want to deploy latest test agent, suggest you to use **Version 2.** instead of 1. for the Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task and try again.

Comment: 1) The agents are not installed on the test machines.2)The issue exists with build definition also. We tried on another test agent(Win 10) and the issue was reproduced, however on Windows 2012 R2 we get the following error: 'An object at the specified path C:\DtaLogs\DTAExecutionHost.exe.log does not exist.