# TFS Build B fails to deploy testAgent while Build A succeeds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I kind of inherited the architecture from a colleague who now is on sick leave, so I can't provide everything about our settings, sorry:

I do have a physical server with a VSO agent running interactively (we want to perform GUI tests).
There is Build_A, which can easily perform the build step "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" on this server (and run the tests subsequently).

Now I want to run the tests from the Build where the software to be tested is actually built, triggered by CheckIns, but the deployment step fails if executed from there, saying that access was denied when connecting to the server.
The suggested Link http://aka.ms/remotevstest did not provide help.

- When I clone Build_A as "Build_A_clone", this clone can deploy the Agent (so this step does not seem to be to confined to a certain build).
- When I clone Build_B and name the clone "Build_A_clone", this clone also fails (so the server does not seem to be restricted to accept builds only by name).
- Both Builds are within the same project, an the agent pool under which the VSO agent is registered does not change the behaviour.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I missed some important information or some helpful article (e.g. I'm also experiencing [Deploy TestAgent fails with unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586005/deploy-testagent-fails-with-unhandled-exception) when deploying the agent from a TFS release, but no article seems to have the issue between Builds. "Winrm quickconfig" and "Enable-PSRemoting" as suggested  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390236 also did not help).
Also, all settings are the same between Builds, e.g. "Update test agent" is enabled on both, disabling it does not solve the problem).

Comment: Did you have multiple agents in your an agent pool? And what's detail error info did you get when you run build B?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you manually recreate a new build definition with the same steps instead of directly cloning definition B.

Besides, if you have multiples agents in the agent pool. You could specify an agent to run the build for both Build A and Build B. This will narrow down if the issue is related to the build agent.

Detail steps about how to specify a build agent in vNext build please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341041/how-to-specify-a-build-agent-in-vnext-build).